# Draw a Grid over a Picturebox in c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am trying to make a tool in c# which allows the user to put a grid on the screen on a picturebox. At the moment i don't know how to do this, so when a button is clicked, the picturebox comes up with a grid. It needs to be a grid which is spaced out enough that users can find out locations of objects on the picture in the picturebox. Help with what code i can use to do this would be very helpful as i was going to use ControlPaint.DrawGrid but not sure of the values i need to put in it to get my desired effect?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Form the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlpaint.drawgrid.aspx) od controlpaint.Drawgrid,

I suppose you need to decide on the cell size in x- amd y-direction and pass this as a size parameter to Drawgrid:

```
public static void DrawGrid(
    Graphics graphics,
    Rectangle area,
    Size pixelsBetweenDots,
    Color backColor
)
```

for example, a 100*200 pixels square grid would be generated by

- setting *graphcis* to the context you want to draw upon,
- Setting area to the top left right and bottom parameters of your image
- setting size.x to 100 and size.y to 200
- setting color to any color you like.

**Update**
Something like this should do.

```
Rectangle myRect = new System.drawings.Rectangle();
myRect.Location := new System.Drawing.Point(0,0);
myRect.Height = 50;
myRect.Width = 50;

Drawgrid(FromImage(yourImage), mygrid , yourImage.Size, System.Drawing.Color.Black);
```

Disclaimer: i don't develope in c#, so above code is not tested for anything. I just picked stuff from the documentation (msdn).

Comment: This is super, can you give me some values to put in to these variables/parameters for it to work please, so i can see how and what i need to enter so i can edit to my desired needs please.

Comment: I appreciate your help but it still does not work, so am still unsure of how to do this grid??

Comment: Could you please Post the source code in which you try to draw the grid?

Comment: This is my current code of what he has supplied to me, i don't know any code of how to draw a grid on it. So i have no code.